# Is it worth using a relocation service to move to the Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, relocation

My family and I are looking to relocate from the UK to the Netherlands ASAP (read pre-Brexit, while we still can). We are looking into using a relocation service but are not sure it is worth the expense.

Has anyone found relocation services to be good value for money? What are the pros and cons of their use?

Edit: by relocation service, I do not mean movers (so the people who physically pack your belongings and move them to another country), rather a service that sorts out the particulars of life at your new location, e.g. helps you find a place to live, place your children in nursery or school, sets you up with tax numbers etc, gets you registered with a doctor, etc. etc.

Comment: This risks being closed as opinion based, and the site explicitly discourages requests for recommendations.  But the topic of the question is an excellent one.  Can you rephrase the question in more objective terms?  Asking about advantages versus disadvantages, considerations to keep in mind, and so forth, might be better received.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Tough question. I found it quite useful, takes some of the stress out of appartment hunting, which depending on the size/budget/location is a huge plus (small units move very fast in large cities in the West). But the only time I used one, my employer paid for it and that seems to be the most common scenario. I am not sure I even knew exactly how much it costs so it's difficult to decide whether it's good value for money.

Comment: @GrotesqueSI: Please edit your question to clarify what kind of service you're talking about: The actual physical packing, moving and unpacking of stuff; finding accommodation? arranging for a rental contract? Getting children enrolled in schools? etc.

Comment: Consider it done